# Making Async or Parallel Requests with Django 3.0.1

Tags: python, django

I have as simple view connecting to an API for a number of stocks and saving them in the database:

```
def update (request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        localStocks = Stock.objects.all()
        output = []
        ticker = []
        for local_stock in localStocks:
            api_response = requests.get("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/"+ str(local_stock.ticker) + "/quote/?token="+token)
            ticker.append(local_stock.ticker)
            try:
                data = json.loads(api_response.content)

                output.append (data)
                dic_data = {
                    "symbol": data['symbol'] , 
                    "latestPrice": data['latestPrice'] , 
                    "companyName":  data['companyName'], 
                    "week52High": data['week52High'] , 
                    "week52Low": data['week52Low'] , 
                    "ytdChange": data['ytdChange'] ,
                    "latestTime":  data['latestTime'],  
                    "changePercent": data['changePercent'] , 
                }

                for i in dic_data:
                    setattr(local_stock, i, dic_data[i])
                    print (dic_data[i])
                local_stock.save()

            except Exception as e:
                    api = "%%% DB save Error %%%"
                    print(e)    


    return redirect ("stocks:get_stock")
```

The problem is --even with just 12 stocks -- this code is very slow. 
I read a tutorial at [here](https://julien.danjou.info/python-and-fast-http-clients/) but I am not sure if I should try to use parallel requests or async requests in my code and how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, all you want to do here is get the latest stock values and update that data in your database.
Here your code highly relies on the response time from the iexapis request. I'd suggest you to either fetch data in a batch or move all of your code to a different thread where you first fetch stock value and then update in your db but in a thread.

Some thing like this......

```
def method1:
    some_list=[1,2,3,4]
    for a in some_list:
        t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(a,))
        t.start()
    return True

def func_up():
    #fetch data from api and update in database
    return
```

Comment: Another approach here can be using async requests using async and coroutines.
Make async calls and use returned data to update your database.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I believe that a parallel or async request would yield much better results and address the question. I also think that to have a complete reply you should refer to my code not to placeholder data.